# Scala: Printing the ouput in proper data format using scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, output

I would like to display the data in proper format, I have the below code

```
val maplist=List(Map("id" -> "1", "Name" -> "divya"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "Name" -> "gaya")
)

val header=maplist.flatMap(_.keys).distinct
val data=maplist.map(_.values)
println(header.mkString(" "))
data.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(" ")))
```

this is showing as

```
id  Name
1   divya
2   gaya
```

but I would like to show like, I may have to use df.show() function

```
+----+-----+
|Id  |Name |
+----+-----+
|1   |Divya|
|2   |gaya |
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the separators you should use `mkString` method with more parameters, you can check in the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

> mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String): String
>
> Displays all elements of this traversable or iterator in a string
>   using start, end, and separator strings.

```
  val separatorLine = "+----+-----+"
  val separator = "|"
  val maplist=List(Map("id" -> "1", "Name" -> "divya"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "Name" -> "gaya")
  )

  val header=maplist.flatMap(_.keys).distinct
  val data=maplist.map(_.values)
  println(separatorLine)
  println(header.mkString("|", " |", "|"))
  println(separatorLine)
  data.foreach(x => println(x.mkString("|", " |", "|")))
  println(separatorLine)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+
|id |Name|
+----+-----+
|1 |divya|
|2 |gaya|
+----+-----+
```

Update: If you want to have the same length in every String (for instance 5) you can do an auxiliar method yo append blanks when needed:

```
 @tailrec
  private def appendElem(original : String, desiredLength: Int, c: Char): String = {
    if (original.length < desiredLength)
      appendElem(original + c, desiredLength, c)
    else {
      original
    }
  }
  val separator = "|"
  val maplist=List(Map("id" -> "1", "Name" -> "divya"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "Name" -> "gaya")
  )

  val separatorLine = List.fill(maplist.size)( "+").map(appendElem(_, 6,'-')).mkString+ "+"
  val header=maplist.flatMap(_.keys.map(key => appendElem(key, 5, ' '))).distinct
  val data=maplist.map(_.values)
  println(separatorLine)
  println(header.mkString("|", "|", "|"))
  println(separatorLine)
  data.map(x => x.map(y => appendElem(y, 5, ' '))).foreach(x => println(x.mkString("|", "|", "|")))
  println(separatorLine)
```

With this second version the result is as follows

```
+-----+-----+
|id   |Name |
+-----+-----+
|1    |divya|
|2    |gaya |
+-----+-----+
```